# How do I expose a standard ui layout page as an externally facing website?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-out, external-app

I am planning on adding a few custom objects and require a page to be exposed publicly.  I have looked at both visualforce and lightning out, but am confused about the best practices.  Can I expose a standard UI page layout?  Do I need to host externally (ie: from Node, .Net, Java, etc.) and embed the page?

Update: This site will also have unauthenticated users coming in from an email link to preload some info.

Comment: Have a look at [Communities](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/communities) trailhead

Comment: If you are using salesforce then Communities or using platform licenses are right way to do it. Platform licenses offers low cost login users which can work with and access certain CRM features. Communities are used for larger group or while creating a public facing page. There are a lot of licenses types which can be determined based on exact requirement. If you want to go custom, you can use slds and UI api to create the layout on a server and integrate standard services with it

Comment: Thanks @manjit5190, I just updated above that the site will have unauthenticated users coming in from an email link to preload some info.